# Understanding the additional field in shape dynamics calculation of big bang

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, cosmology, big-bang

I read [this](https://doi.org/10.3390/sym13091712) fascinating paper ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/354756646_Total_Collisions_in_the_N-Body_Shape_Space)).

The total collision is a well-known singularity in Newton mechanics: the distances become zero and, therefore, the potential becomes infinite.

In a paper before that one above, Paula Reichert describes a try to calculate through the singularity using shape dynamics. In shape dynamics, the absolute background space is abandoned and only relative positions and especially angles are considered. Unfortunately, shape dynamics alone turns out not to be  sufficient to calculate through the singularity.

Then, in the paper above, they make a reference to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2018.01.055) where they calculate through the big bang singularity by adding a scalar "stiff matter" field in the Bianchi IX universe.

How can one understand this scalar field?
Since shape dynamics doesn't rely on an absolute space as a background, it comes to my mind that this scalar field may be interpreted as space itself, space that surrounds every single mass point as a field.
Is that interpretation right or wrong?

If wrong, how can one get an understanding for this scalar field?

Comment: More on [shape dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22shape+dynamics%22).